# My Preview is messed up - now saving as .png - how to get it back to saving in .jpg like it has been?

Tags: macos, preview

my workflow is I open a .jpg image contact sheet, drag over a selection, edit , copy , new from clipboard and name the image -> copied image is now new_image.jpg.

Now , they are automatically .png when I go to rename the copy - Preview is changing the .jpg to .png after the copy.

I want them to stay .jpg - like the original.

I haven't made any OS changes or the like and cannot figure out whats changed.

Apple tech support says thats expected behavior - Preview is suppose to save as .png.  Then I ask, so why was it not doing that the past 2 years ive been doing this.

Is there a way to get it back to .jpg?  Running Ventura 13.6.1  Tks.

Answer (score 0):

You'll see that people have been asking how to change the default save format of Preview for several years, so the behaviour has not changed.

[Can Mac Preview be set to default to save image as JPEG](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/380644/can-mac-preview-be-set-to-default-to-save-image-as-jpeg)

[Is there a way to change the default save/export format in Preview?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/363674/is-there-a-way-to-change-the-default-save-export-format-in-preview)

[How can the default save format be changed for OS X Preview app?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/373409/how-can-the-default-save-format-be-changed-for-os-x-preview-app)

Any New document will default to PNG. Duplicates or modified versions of existing files will retain their format.

The act of copying image data to the clipboard will 'lose' any file format association.

Comment: That’s the stumper - for 2 years now I’ve been copying out of a.jpg and then new from clipboard and all the files have stayed .jpg. Now all of sudden as of last night , they are .png for some reason.  Just trying to get back the old way….  I don’t understand what’s changed.

Comment: ok, mistake on my part - senior moment & got Apps / programs mixed up.  My copying from Preview has been .png's - which I mixed up with my scanning output of images which has been .jpg's.  Sorry and thanks for the quick replies.    Maybe ill ask to have this thread deleted....